# Textures not appearing on autodesk models when I import them

Tags: modeling, texturing

I'm bit of noob when it comes to blender so I was wondering why when I import .fbx models into blender the textures do not appear even when I select the texture option?

Comment: Did you check for errors?

Comment: I've just reimported it now and blender isn't displaying any errors.

Comment: Hmm . . . No textures, no errors, rather odd. I found a diferent question on here that had a similar issue, but it didn't have an answer. One thought, do you have to select some option to bundle textures on the application that exports the fbx file?

Comment: I've just been mssing around with the model and it appears that when I choose to view the model in render mode it dispalys the texture.

Comment: Cool! So this is actually not an issue then?

Comment: It should also display in solid or material view. You just didn't use a diffuse tex.

Comment: @VinceScalia Note that textures won't be displayed in solid view by default, you'll need to enable *Textured solid* in *3D view > Properties region* (`N`).

Comment: @gandalf3 sorry, I meant to write textured.